# Can you identify this fiery orange hair?

Tags: part-identification, minifigures

Can someone identify the orange hair in this minifig?

[image: fiery minifig]

Answer (score 7):

That seems to be part #24787, [Minifigure, Hair Spiked Tall Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=24787#T=C). So far it has only been released in orange. It came on the 2016 [Syndrome](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=dis014#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) minifig, one of the [Disney Collectible Minifigures](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=coldis-14#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).